# Django Migration from 2.0 to 2.2(View Permissions Issue)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin, django-2.1, django-permissions

While Migrating the Django Facing issue related to migration :

> python manage.py migrate demo --database demo

Getting Error related to :

> ValueError: Cannot assign "ContentType: ContentType object (1)": the current database router prevents this relation.

```
Detailed Error Log : https://ideone.com/z6NPkq
```

**Tested Django Version**: After Django version **2.0.13**, facing this issue.

Let me know what could be the reason for this?

**EDIT**: Found the reason in Django 2.1, They have added view Permission: [Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.1/#what-s-new-in-django-2-1)

Why the view permissions are not generating automatically?

**Solution**: In Django module, if We will move to file path: django/contrib/auth/management/__init.py

We have to change Line Number: 79

```
Permission(codename=codename, name=name, content_type=ct)
```

to

```
Permission(codename=codename, name=name, content_type_id=ct.id)
```

I have found this solution after debugging inside the Django but still unable to understand why this is happening. Let me know other solution and any reason for this solution.

**EDIT-1**: Looking for an answer so that I don't have to change the core Django module(Library).

**Solution-1** :

```
def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    if obj1._state.db == "demo" or obj2._state.db=="demo":
        return True
    return obj1._state.db == obj2._state.db
```

**Note**: In my case, Other databases are using the demo database tables as a reference, so for that in **Approuter class** customized the **allow_relation** method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like a router issue. It should be because you are using Django with multiple database configuration.
You need to overwrite allow_relation function in app router to allow relation between the databases where content-type is present and demo database according to the example above.

Comment: can we see the allow_relation override ? or is it just your suggestions. thanks

Comment: @OhadtheLad I have added a solution in question section